# Mark Outlook Email as Read in Conversation

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Morning Guys,

I turned on conversation view in my inbox so my emails are grouped together. So lets say that I have 5 unread emails in this conversation. When I open the last email I will see the contents of all the other unopened email (minus attachments) once I scroll down the body of the opened email.

This means when I close this email I would have already seen the contents of the remaining 4 mails in the conversation.

So my question is, how can I open the last email and automatically mark the previous ones unread so I don't have to go back and mark 4 other emails as unread as based on my example.

Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Dane

Answer (score 1):

Select the group and just right click and choose "Make as Read" or "Mark as unread"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedack Perry and Erjen. Both of you provided the same solution to which I appreciate. That is a way of doing making a group of emails as read. But is there a solution more in alignment with what I am asking?

Comment: What's your requirement? Only mark the previous one as unread but leave the last one as Read?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the emails as read or unread on the group itself to do this. Not per email. 
So if you receive 5 emails of the same email, mark the grouped email as read and all the emails will be read. Same goes for if you want to unread the whole group.

By the way, you can also select all emails that you want to mark as read or unread and than just right click one email and mark as read.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.